# Salesforce1 for unauthenticated Site pages?

Tags: force.com-sites, salesforce1-app, browser

I need to provide a better mobile interface for unauthenticated Site users, but am getting the error that authentication is required when I try to give them access to Salesforce1 via the browser using /one/one.app appended on the site URL.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce1 is entirely driven from the server based on the user, so you can't access the application without authenticating.  You'd need to replicate the Salesforce1 look and feel through regular Visualforce to give your guests the same experience.

Josh Birk's One Starter (https://github.com/joshbirk/onestarter) should give you a kickstart for this, but I'd still expect it to be a fair amount of work.